# How to delete initiative , features and user stories from Rally?

Tags: java, rally, code-rally

Through Java Rally Rest API, how can I delete initiative , features and user stories? couldn't find the API in the rally.

Comment: Can you use DeleteRequest as described here? https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForJava/wiki/User-Guide#delete

Answer (score 0):

The 'delete' of an item is caused by hitting the end point for the item type ( e.g. https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/hierarchicalrequirement/ObjectID) with the operation set to DELETE (rather than GET or POST). You can test this out using curl if you wish. The file you want to look at is probably this one:

https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForJava/blob/542afa16ea44c9c64cebb0299500dcbbb50b6d7d/src/main/java/com/rallydev/rest/RallyRestApi.java#L152